# Does anyone use Sikuli as a testing tool?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, sikuli

Hi I have a Swing application to test and I found Sikuli a nice tool to do it, but I am a little worried about the size of the community and if it's being continually developed and it's being used by other companies.

Do you use it?

For what?

Is it stable?

Is it the best tool for the job you needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Has anybody used SIKULI for testing their GUI-based apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125839/has-anybody-used-sikuli-for-testing-their-gui-based-apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use it in my company, too. 
It can be used quite easily for not too complex gui-tests. 
Sikuli was not developed for the last year but development is now increasing again. 
Questions in the Sikuli-FAQ section on launchpad are answered fast although the community is not that big. 
In my company, Sikuli is used for gui testing which was previously done by human testers. 
It saves some time but not everything is automatable with Sikuli, e.g. the OCR functionality is not dependable (but will be updated from tesseract 2.04 to 3 in the near future).

For my job it was the best tool because it is the only open source (=free) tool I found that provides screenshot based automation that can be integrated with other systems like CI-systems and is programmable with Java and Python which makes easy unit testing possible with JUnit or PyUnit.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we use it in-house for testing. It is actively supported.  I have reported bugs in Sikuli and have had tickets and workarounds suggested within days with the bugs fixed in the next revision.

It is quite stable.  The problems I have encountered typically come from not specifying images correctly and the program selecting an incorrect area of the screen.

One of our more unique uses was creating a set of automated bench tests for a legacy embedded system.  The system was written in assembly and had no unit testing capabilities.  It communicated with a custom legacy PC application.  Rather than try to locate the PC source code, reverse engineer the design, and then write some meaningful bench tests, we created a number of Sikuli scripts to interface with the PC app.  It saved weeks of development.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we use it for automating GUI tests. It's used mostly for old systems that were developed with no test driven back end. (ie: no testing api)

We tests some very complex tools including a debugger using Sikuli.

We tend not to use the Sikuli IDE though.